# Overwrite values of dictionary without memory allocation in Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

I am using Julia 1.9.0.

`P`, `Q`, `R`, and `S` are dictionaries whose keys are the same such as

```
P = Dict("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3)
Q = Dict("a"=>2, "b"=>4, "c"=>2)
R = Dict("a"=>2, "b"=>4, "c"=>5)
S = Dict("a"=>4, "b"=>9, "c"=>1)
```

I want to overwrite the dict `P` with the sum of `Q`, `R`, `S` on the same keys. I mean, I would like to get

```
P = merge(+, [Q,R,S]...)
```

Can we do that without memory allocation? I will use dicts `Q`, `R`, and `S` later, so they cannot be overwritten. But I do not need `P` anymore. That is why only `P` can be overwritten.

My current code `P = merge(+, [Q,R,S]...)` requires the memory allocation. I am finding alternatives without (or less) memory allocation.

```
using BenchamrkTools
@btime P = merge(+, [Q,R,S]...)
1.583 μs (10 allocations: 736 bytes)
```

**Edit**

For simplicity, I am just describing a situation when the number of keys is 3. But actually, the number of keys is ~10k, and the number of dictionaries is ~20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
mergewith!(+, mergewith!((x,y)->y, P, Q), R, S)
```

Inner `mergewith!` overwrites P with Q, the outer `mergewith!` adds the other Dicts' values.

There must be a pre-defined function for `(x,y)->y`. Someone in a comment help me out...

EDIT: Improved due to Gnimuc and BallpointBen comments:

```
mergewith!(+, merge!(P, Q), R, S)
```

Ah, the benchmark:

```
julia> @btime mergewith!(+, merge!($P, $Q), $R, $S);
  100.487 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
Dict{String, Int64} with 3 entries:
  "c" => 8
  "b" => 17
  "a" => 8
```

There are still more efficiency gains to be made if the dictionaries are the same concrete type.

ADDED: Per comment just above, here is another method to get comparable speed:

```
foreach(keys(P)) do k
    P[k] = sum(D[k] for D in (Q,R,S))
end
```

and for the reckless and danger seeking (think racecars):

```
foreach(keys(P)) do k
    index = Base.ht_keyindex(P, k)
    P.vals[index] = sum(D.vals[index] for D in (Q,R,S))
end
```

These benchmark:

```
julia> @btime foreach(keys($P)) do k
       $P[k] = sum(D[k] for D in ($Q,$R,$S))
       end
  103.624 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime foreach(keys($P)) do k
       index = Base.ht_keyindex($P, k)
       $P.vals[index] = sum(D.vals[index] for D in ($Q,$R,$S))
       end
  31.562 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

That is, the first is comparable, and the second is significantly faster (but depends crucially on similarity of Dict implementation and construction).

Comment: > There must be a pre-defined function for (x,y)->y. Someone in a comment help me out... `mergewith!(+, copy!($P, $Q), $R, $S)`

Comment: You can just use `merge!`, which always takes from the latter argument(s) if there are duplicate keys.

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks your comment. Do you mean I should do `merge!(+, P, Q, R, S)`?
If all values in P are 0, it works. However, in general, I do not think it works. Please let me know if I made some mistakes.

Comment: @BallpointBen `merge!` and `mergewith!` are the same. `merge!` was the older name, but `mergewith!` is preferred (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.mergewith!)

Comment: `merge!(P, Q)` will update `P` with `Q`. `mergewith!` is only preferred when you provide a function to combine with. `merge!(dicts...)` just always breaks ties by taking from the last dict passed.

Comment: @BallpointBen you are right. There are subtle differences in the implementations of `copy!`, `merge!` and `mergewith!`. Without a combining function, `copy!` empties the destination Dict which is more expensive than just an update with `merge!`. Speaking of updates, I'll update the answer to use `merge!`.